# Sonarqube Custom Java plugin: Unsatisfied Dependency Error on Sensor initialization

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am developing a custom java plugin to add some i18n checks, but got an Unsatisfied Dependency error on my Custom sensor. Could you help me out? Thanks a lot, I'm new to sonarqube...and i did have searched on similar issues but not got sorted.

Details pls find below: feel free to ask if any more info needed

- SonarSever: 7.5
- Sonar-java: sonar-java-plugin-5.9.2.16552.jar
- custom language: i18njava
- custom profile: I18NProfile

I'm writing my Sensor referring to the JavaSquidSensor impl.

Here below is my Senor class:

```
@Phase(name = Phase.Name.PRE)
@DependsUpon("BEFORE_SQUID")
@DependedUpon("squid")
public class I18NJavaPreCheckSensor implements Sensor {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(I18NJavaPreCheckSensor.class);
    private static final JavaHardCodedCheck hcc = new JavaHardCodedCheck();

    private final SonarComponents sonarComponents;
    private final DefaultJavaResourceLocator javaResourceLocator;
    private final Configuration settings;
    private final NoSonarFilter noSonarFilter;
    private final PostAnalysisIssueFilter postAnalysisIssueFilter;
    private final FileSystem fs;

    public I18NJavaPreCheckSensor(SonarComponents sonarComponents, @Nullable FileSystem fs,
                                  @Nullable DefaultJavaResourceLocator javaResourceLocator, @Nullable Configuration settings, @Nullable NoSonarFilter noSonarFilter, @Nullable PostAnalysisIssueFilter postAnalysisIssueFilter) {
        System.out.println("nos: " +noSonarFilter.toString());
        this.noSonarFilter = noSonarFilter;
        this.sonarComponents = sonarComponents;
        this.javaResourceLocator = javaResourceLocator;
        this.settings = settings;
        this.postAnalysisIssueFilter = postAnalysisIssueFilter;
        System.out.println("postAnalysisIssueFilter: " +postAnalysisIssueFilter.toString());
        this.fs = fs;
        System.out.println("fs: " +fs.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void describe(SensorDescriptor descriptor) {
        descriptor.onlyOnLanguage(Constants.LANGUAGE_KEY).name("I18NJavaPreCheckSensor");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(SensorContext context) {
            javaResourceLocator.setSensorContext(context);
            sonarComponents.setSensorContext(context);

            List<Class<? extends JavaCheck>> checks = ImmutableList.<Class<? extends JavaCheck>>builder()
                    .addAll(I18NCheckClasses.getJavaChecks())
                    .build();
            sonarComponents.registerCheckClasses(I18NJavaRulesDefinition.REPOSITORY_KEY, checks);
            sonarComponents.registerTestCheckClasses(I18NJavaRulesDefinition.REPOSITORY_KEY,I18NCheckClasses.getJavaTestChecks());
            Measurer measurer = new Measurer(fs, context, noSonarFilter);
            I18NJavaSquid squid = new I18NJavaSquid(getJavaVersion(), isXFileEnabled(), sonarComponents, measurer, javaResourceLocator, postAnalysisIssueFilter, sonarComponents.checkClasses());
            squid.scan(getSourceFiles(), getTestFiles());
            sonarComponents.saveAnalysisErrors();

    }
    }
```

I run from the sonar scanner, and got the error below:

```
16:06:04.781 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException: i18n.sensor.I18NJavaPreCheckSensor has unsatisfied dependency 'class org.sonar.java.filters.PostAnalysisIssueFilter' for constructor 'public i18n.sensor.I18NJavaPreCheckSensor(org.sonar.java.SonarComponents,org.sonar.api.batch.fs.FileSystem,org.sonar.java.DefaultJavaResourceLocator,org.sonar.api.config.Configuration,org.sonar.api.issue.NoSonarFilter,org.sonar.java.filters.PostAnalysisIssueFilter)' from org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer@22c01ab0:151<[Immutable]:org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer@63a270c9:218<[Immutable]:org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer@4f4c4b1a:9<[Immutable]:org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer@53dfacba:37<|
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:191)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.access$100(ConstructorInjector.java:51)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:331)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:606)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponents(DefaultPicoContainer.java:587)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentsByType(ComponentContainer.java:290)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerExtensionDictionnary.completeScannerExtensions(ScannerExtensionDictionnary.java:118)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerExtensionDictionnary.getExtensions(ScannerExtensionDictionnary.java:113)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerExtensionDictionnary.getFilteredExtensions(ScannerExtensionDictionnary.java:103)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerExtensionDictionnary.selectSensors(ScannerExtensionDictionnary.java:77)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:55)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:74)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:164)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:319)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:314)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:288)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:131)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:137)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:111)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

Comment: Cross posted here: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/custom-java-plugin-unsatisfied-dependency-error-on-sensor-initialization/8843

Comment: It looks like your exception is happening in the scanner, which runs separately from Sonar Server and Compute Engine, so does not have access to all the same class instances as are available in core. Is your code publicly hosted to help provide some pointers around splitting it up into relevant components?